# Communicate issue between High-level and RTapp

Tags: azure-sphere

i am trying to create high-level app based on IntercoreComms samples from azsure-sphere-samples, the high level sample code itself it's working w/o issue on my mt3620 dev board, but when i try to add my code on top of it and run it, there is error message as below from high-level app.

ERROR: Unable to create socket: 13 (Permission denied)

and, the error message from RTApp is as below.

TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State

---

0* io0                cortex_m   little mt3620.cpu         unknown

Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 23 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 4800 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477
Info : io0: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : io0: external reset detected
Info : Listening on port 4444 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/4444
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x001008ea msp: 0x0012fb90
Warn : target io0 is not halted (gdb fileio)
Polling target io0 failed, trying to reexamine
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x3ba02477

Answer (score 0):

To give permission for your high-level app to talk to your real-time app, and vice versa, the "AllowedApplicationConnections" field of the app_manifest.json for each app must contain the component ID of the other app.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/high-level-inter-app#app-manifest-settings) for details.  The "ComponentId" is itself a field in the app manfiest: your new app(s) likely have different IDs to the sample apps.

Also, if you are deploying through Visual Studio (Code), you need to declare each app as a 'partner' of the other so one is not deleted when the other is deployed. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/sideload-app#mark-applications-as-partners) for details of that. The RT app error that you see may come from it being deleted when the high-level app is deployed.